# Parse from end to start of a String to grab data before the third occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: java, string, delimiter

I am working on some strings and trying to parse through the data and retrieve a string that lies before the third occurrence of " - " from the end of the string. This data comes as a String from the DB and there is some text "-NONE----" that I would like to exclude while parsing.

Input (Below input is a String and not List)

```
String input1 = "-A123456-B987-013691-000-109264821"
String input2 = "-NONE----"
String input3 = "C1234567-A1241-EF-012361-000-18273460"
```

Output

```
String output1 = "-A123456-B987"
String output2= "-NONE----"
String output3 = "C1234567-A1241-EF"
```

Starting from the beginning of my string, I need to retrieve data before the third occurrence of
" - " (hyphen) is found, but I need to count " - " (hyphen) occurrence starting from end of string.

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the three dashes from behind with the `$` symbol and then extract everything that is in front of that. I created two capture groups, where the first one is what you want to extract:

```
private static String extractFront(String input1) {
    if(input1.equals("-NONE----")) {
       return input1;
    } else {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(-[^-]*){3}$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input1);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Main to test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "-A123456-B987-013691-000-109264821";
    String input2 = "-NONE----";
    String input3 = "C1234567-A1241-EF-012361-000-18273460";

    System.out.println(extractFront(input1));
    System.out.println(extractFront(input2));
    System.out.println(extractFront(input3));
}
```

Output:

```
-A123456-B987
-NONE----
C1234567-A1241-EF
```

EDIT: @stubbleweb1995 added the `if` condition for a complete solution

Comment: Thank you for the help @JANO. it works as intended, I added one more if condition to the code to parse -NONE---- as it is and not apply Regex to that text.

Comment: You're welcome! I missed that the dashes should stay in the NONE case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex replacement approach:

```java
String input = "-A123456-B987-013691-000-109264821";
String output = "([^-]*(?:-[^-]+){2}).*", "$1");
System.out.println(output);  // -A123456-B987
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `(` open capture group

  - `[^-]*` match optional first term
  - `(?:-[^-]+){2}` then match - and a term, twice
- `)` close capture group, available as `$1`
- `.*` consume the remainder of the string

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Tim and DevilsHnd.

I am getting an error in the Regex when I try to use it both on Regex101 and my IDE.

https://regex101.com/r/18bpLq/1

IDE

String output = "([^-]*(?:-[^-]+){2}).*", "$1");

"$1" - This part shows an error stating "Not a statement".

I am trying to pass a String to method and return the trimmed value.

Answer (score 1):

We can use streams, lambdas, and predicate.

Split your input on its end-of-line character, to get an array of strings. We filter out  the “NONE” lines.

For each line, we split into pieces, using the hyphen as a delimiter. This gives us an array of strings that we reassemble using only the 3 parts.

Lastly we collect into a list.

Here is some untested code to get you started.

```
String[] lines = input.split( "\n" ) ;
List < String > results = 
    Arrays
    .stream( lines ) 
    .filter( line -> ! line.contains( "-NONE-" )
    .map(
        line -> {
            String.join( 
                "-" ,
                Arrays.copyOf( line.split( "-" , 4 ) , 3 , String[].class )
            )
        }
    )
    .toList() 
 ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Basil and I am sorry that I didn't describe the problem well. The input I will be passing would be individual strings and not a List<String>. I have edited the question to reflect this information. 

Thank you for the help.